# WebSocketApp vs create_connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I was wondering if someone could explain the difference between:

```
ws = websocket.create_connection('wss://echo.websocket.org')
```

and

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://echo.websocket.org')
```

within the Python package `websocket`, as the docs aren't very clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`create_connection` is a factory function that generates a websocket class from the one provided in the `class_` keyword argument, [`websocket.WebSocket`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/df275d351f9887fba2774e2e1aa79ff1e5a24bd1/websocket/_core.py#L51) by default. This class provides low-level interface but can be used directly for code that just needs to interact with the websocket imperatively - send message, wait for response, send next message - and so on.

`WebSocketApp` is a wrapper around `WebSocket` that provides a more 'event-driven' interface. You provide callbacks to the constructor (or by assignment to the relevant members after initialization), then call `run_forever` which blocks until the connection is closed. When messages come, the `WebSocketApp` calls your callback functions. This could drive your whole app, or you could call `run_forever` in a different thread and do other work at the same time (such as updating game state periodically based on a timer instead of only when messages are received).